# React navigation: how to debug

Tags: debugging, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app where I configured multiple routes and everything was working fine until this latest route that I configured and does not work (the wrong screen is shown).

My question is how can I go about debugging? No error log is printed and I can't find how to get more logs about what's happening. Nor do I know where to stop with the debugger to get some useful info.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem and it will be very helpful if you will also attach your code?

Comment: @AndreiZgîrvaci I just figured out the issue and this was an issue with the state that was getting changed in Redux. The questions remain though, how can I debug the navigation if an issue arises? Is there a way to get the library to print log statement when the navigation change or something?

Comment: I am having difficulty with this too. I would think when distributing a library the first line in your documentation would be. To turn on logging during debug do this. Or at least the second line. I would like to see this is any getting started example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Where to Log

You can use this 2 listeners in order to log something:

`willFocus` - the screen will focus

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", () => console.log(""));
}
```

`willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.addListener("willBlur", () => console.log(""));
}
```

Also, take a look at the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to see more listeners.

### What to Log

Get the state of the `navigator` at the time of the event with:

```
let state = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetState();
```

From here, you can see the available routes with `state.routeNames`. You can also see the current navigation stack (the history of all the navigation events used to perform actions like `goBack`) with `state.routes`.